# Rails 4 fields_for not saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like to save article_id in photos model via fields_for but doesn't work.

article.rb

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :category
    has_many :photos
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos
```

photo.rb:

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :article
```

category.rb

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :articles
```

articles_controller.rb

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @article = Article.new
    @category  = Category.find(params[:category])
    @article.photos.build
  end

  def create
    @article = current_user.articles.build(article_params)
    @article.save

   |
   |
   |

private

def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:content, :category_id, photos_attributes: [:id, :article_id])
end
```

_article_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@article) do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :category_id %>
    <%= f.text_area :content %>
    <%= f.fields_for :photos do |p| %>
      <%= p.hidden_field :article_id %>
    <% end %>
  <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

.schema articles

```
CREATE TABLE "articles" (
"id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, 
"content" varchar(255), 
"user_id" integer, 
"category_id" integer,
"created_at" datetime, 
"updated_at" datetime);
```

.schema categories

```
CREATE TABLE "categories" (
"id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, 
"code" integer, 
"created_at" datetime, 
"updated_at" datetime);
```

---

Thanks rmagnum2002.

In articles_controller.rb, I added as followings;

```
private

def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:content)
end
```

But I didn't have article_id.
How can I write code for article_id?

---

Thanks Rich Peck.

Althogh I edited articles_controller.rb, I had NoMethodError in ArticlesController#new.
undefined method `build_photo' for #

```
articles_controller.rb

  def new
    @article = Article.new
    @article.build_photo
```

Comment: For the latter error, you need to use `@article.photos.build` instead. As `build_photo` is used when **Article** is associated to **Photo** with a `has_one` association.

Comment: One more thing you'd need to do to in order to make it work. Add this line to your **Article** model `accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos`. You can read more about the same [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html).

Comment: Thanks to all of you, I could save article_id in photos model via fields_for.

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= f.fields_for :photo do |p| %>
```

We had this issue a few months back; [`fields_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for) is part of your `form_for` object, and consequently won't submit unless it's called *on* the form object (with `f.`).

The rails guide is very misleading with this method - you need to call it with `f.` to get it to pass the data to your params.

--

**Controller**

If you're using `f.fields_for`, you also need to `build` your associative data in your controller:

```
#app/controllers/articles_controller.rb
Class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @article = Article.new
      @article.build_photo #-> build_value is for singluar association; values.build is for multiple
   end

   def create
      @aticle = Article.new(article_params)
      @article.save
   end

   private 

   def article_params
       params.require(:article).permit(photo_attributes: [:your, :attributes])
   end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice.It worked `photos_attributes` (plural)